# Selenium send_keys - method sends xpath( Python abnormal behavior )

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, authentication, sendkeys

I am working on a Tinder project and for that I would like to log in with google. I managed to hide from and I could log in with success, however when I use the send_keys method to send my email, it sends the xpath of the email input element along side with the email( also it sends the wait method which is at the end of my code). it is a weird behavior, do you know how to solve it?

CODE:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://tinder.com/')

wait()
current_driver = driver.current_window_handle

wait()
login = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='button')
login.click()
wait()
wait()

accept_cookeis = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button')
wait()
accept_cookeis.click()
wait()
main_page = driver.current_window_handle
wait()
google_login = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/span/div[1]/div/button/span[2]')
wait()
google_login.click()
wait()
my_windows = driver.window_handles
wait()

for window in my_windows:
    if window != main_page:
        driver.switch_to.window(window)
        wait()
        email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        wait()
        email_input.send_keys(YOUR_EMAIL)
        time.sleep(1000)
```

[Here's what the method sends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad6kN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used a JavaScript snippet and it solved the problem, however I still don't know what causes this.

Example:

```html
driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import time
```

at beginning of your code.
so that,

```
time.sleep(1000)
```

works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However as I see this has nothing to do with my concern.